# How to add an onchange event to select tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, onchange

How do I add an onchange event here?

Framework: rails
Database: MySQL

I am populating the options from the database and that made me use `options_from_collection_for_select`

```
select_tag(:variable,options_from_collection_for_select(:all, :id, :name))
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001698) takes an `options` hash as its final parameter, in which you can add any HTML attributes for the select. So to add an `onchange` attribute:

```
select_tag :variable, options_from_collection_for_select(:all, :id, :name), onchange: 'yourOnChangeHandler()'
```

Comment: will i be able to specify an action in a controller as an onchange event? if not, how do i do it then?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: i have an action in my controller to be executed and not a javascript event hander. will i be able able to do it with onchange event or are there any other ways?

Comment: DOM events can only fire javascript event handlers. You could have your event handler make an AJAX call to the action you want executed, though.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do of course, but take a look at the observe_field (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001622) method -- you can use that instead of the above onchange handler to set up a Rails action to be called when an input is changed. Hopefully that will put you in the right direction!

Comment: not working!!!  here's my code `<% tax = options_from_collection_for_select(@taxes, 'rate', 'name'),  :onchange => 'calcInvoiceTotal()' %>`

Answer (score 8):

try something like:

```
:onchange => remote_function(:url => {:controller => 'controller', :action => 'action'})
```

Comment: this works only with the prototype helpers, that are excluded from Rails 3.0.9 http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_function

Answer (score 7):

For a select_tag, just add:

```
{:onchange => "myHandler();" }
```

Also, if onchange doesn't work you might want to try `onChange` with a capital C.

Finally, make sure NOT TO CONFUSE a select_tag with a form select.

See my answer to a similar question, only regarding a form select and not a select_tag

[Adding An Onchange Event To A Form Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690516/select-and-onchange-in-a-ruby-on-rails-form/26127746#26127746)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add an `onchange` attribute inline:

```
select_tag(:variable,options_from_collection_for_select(:all, :id, :name)), {:onchange => "(function(e){ e.target.value }).apply(this,arguments)"}
```

For my case, I'm not sure where to put the named functions, or sometimes I find it tedious to create a function just to create a simple tag. So people tend to write an inline function.

but a simple line like `{onchange: "e.target.value"}` won't work, because there are no variables (e.g. `event`) defined.

Solution would be a self executing function that accepts arguments

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? Maybe explain why that would help.